# No me deja ejecutar un JFrame form

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy haciendo una calculadora en Java, pero para ver el resultado de como va yendo, me da el error de que no tengo main, ya que si que lo tengo. Al ejecutar la aplicación me da el error de **class does not have a main method**
No sé si debo poner el main en otro lado, pero siempre me ha funcionado así.
Me podríais ayudar a encontrar el error? gracias!
⠀⠀⠀⠀

````
package TareaTema8;

public class Ejercicio3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
       
    private boolean punto=true;
    String valor1,valor2,signo,contenido;
    Double resultado;
    
    /** Creates new form Ejercicio3 */
    public Ejercicio3() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        BotonMostrar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Numero4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero0 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Numero3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonSuma = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonResta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonPunto = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonBorrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonMulti = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonDividir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonC = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonIgual = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Numero4.setText("4");
        Numero4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero1.setText("1");
        Numero1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero7.setText("7");
        Numero7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero8.setText("8");
        Numero8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero5.setText("5");
        Numero5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero2.setText("2");
        Numero2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero0.setText("0");
        Numero0.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero0ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero9.setText("9");
        Numero9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero6.setText("6");
        Numero6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Numero3.setText("3");
        Numero3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Numero3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        BotonSuma.setText("+");

        BotonResta.setText("-");

        BotonPunto.setText(".");

        BotonBorrar.setText("Supr");

        BotonMulti.setText("x");

        BotonDividir.setText("/");

        BotonC.setText("C");

        BotonIgual.setText("=");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(Numero1)
                                    .add(Numero4)
                                    .add(Numero7))
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(Numero2)
                                    .add(Numero5)
                                    .add(Numero8))
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(Numero3)
                                    .add(Numero6)
                                    .add(Numero9)))
                            .add(Numero0, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(BotonResta)
                            .add(BotonSuma)
                            .add(BotonPunto))
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(BotonBorrar)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(BotonDividir)
                                    .add(BotonIgual)
                                    .add(BotonMulti))
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                .add(BotonC)))
                        .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .add(BotonMostrar))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(BotonMostrar, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(BotonSuma, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                            .add(BotonResta, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                                .add(BotonPunto, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .add(BotonIgual, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(Numero7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                    .add(Numero4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                    .add(Numero1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(Numero8, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                    .add(Numero5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                    .add(Numero2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(Numero9, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                    .add(Numero6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                    .add(Numero3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                            .add(Numero0, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(BotonBorrar, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(BotonMulti, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                                .add(BotonDividir, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .add(BotonC, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void Numero5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BotonMostrar.setText(BotonMostrar.getText()+"5");
    }                                       

    private void Numero0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BotonMostrar.setText(BotonMostrar.getText()+"0");
    }                                       

    private void Numero9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BotonMostrar.setText(BotonMostrar.getText()+"9");
    }                                                                              


        public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejercicio3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejercicio3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejercicio3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ejercicio3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ejercicio3().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonBorrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonC;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonDividir;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonIgual;
    private javax.swing.JTextField BotonMostrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonMulti;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonPunto;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonResta;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonSuma;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero0;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero1;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero2;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero3;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero4;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero5;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero6;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero7;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero8;
    private javax.swing.JButton Numero9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```     ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎          ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎‎      ‏‏‎
````

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado, lo que pasaba es que daba error con la versión 12.0 de netbeans al instalarme la versión 12.3 ya no me aparece el error del main.